# How to change TabbedPage partial icon color in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I am dealing with TabbedPage in Xamarin. However there is a problem that is: How can I change the icon color only partially when Tab is selected. This is the example I want:

[image]

In Xamarin it has a solution to change part of the image color. Or is it changing the icon when Tab is selected. This is the code I handle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            BackgroundColor="#fff"
            ....>    
    <views:Page1 Title="Page 1" IconImageSource="homeicon" BackgroundColor="#fff"/>
    <views:Page2 Title="Page 2" IconImageSource="feeds" BackgroundColor="#fff"/>    
    <views:Page3 Title="Page 3" IconImageSource="chats" BackgroundColor="#fff" />
    <views:Page4 Title="Page 4" IconImageSource="usericon" BackgroundColor="#fff"/>
</TabbedPage>
```

MyTabbedPageRenderer iOS

```
public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        
    }
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        if (TabBar?.Items == null)
            return;

        foreach (var item in TabBar.Items)
        {
            item.Image = ScalingImageToSize(item.Image, new CGSize(20, 20)); // set the size here as you want 
        }

        var tabs = Element as TabbedPage;
        if (tabs != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < TabBar.Items.Length; i++)
            {
                UpdateTabBarItem(TabBar.Items[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    private void UpdateTabBarItem(UITabBarItem item)
    {
        if (item == null) return;

        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
        {
            UITabBarAppearance app = new UITabBarAppearance();
            app.ConfigureWithOpaqueBackground();
            app.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

            app.StackedLayoutAppearance.Normal.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes() { Font = UIFont.FromName("Roboto Medium", 12), ForegroundColor = Color.FromHex("#808080").ToUIColor() };
            app.StackedLayoutAppearance.Selected.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes() { Font = UIFont.FromName("Roboto Medium", 13), ForegroundColor = Color.FromHex("#00AA13").ToUIColor() };
            item.StandardAppearance = app;

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(15, 0))
            {
                item.ScrollEdgeAppearance = item.StandardAppearance;
            }
        }

    }
    public UIImage ScalingImageToSize(UIImage sourceImage, CGSize newSize)
    {

        if (UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 2.0) //@2x iPhone 6 7 8 
        {
            UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 2.0f);
        }


        else if (UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 3.0) //@3x iPhone 6p 7p 8p...
        {
            UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 3.0f);
        }

        else
        {
            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(newSize);
        }

        sourceImage.Draw(new CGRect(0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height));

        UIImage newImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

        return newImage;

    }

}
```

AppDelegate.cs

```
UITabBar.Appearance.BackgroundImage = new UIImage();
UITabBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
UITabBar.Appearance.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0, 170, 19);
```

And the results it shows:

[image]

How can I change the icon color only partially when Tab is selected in android and iOS. Ask for help. Thanks

**Update**

I updated as per your sample, but it still doesn't seem to work. I have created a new project

MainView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Appssss.Views"
            x:Class="Appssss.Views.Mainview">
  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
    <views:Page1 Title="Page 1" IconImageSource="homeicon" BackgroundColor="#fff"/>
    <views:Page2 Title="Page 2" IconImageSource="feeds" BackgroundColor="#fff"/>
    <views:Page3 Title="Page 3" IconImageSource="moneys" BackgroundColor="#fbfbfb" />
    <views:Page4 Title="Page 4" IconImageSource="chats" BackgroundColor="#fff" />
    <views:Page5 Title="Page 5" IconImageSource="usericon" BackgroundColor="#fff"/>
</TabbedPage>
```

MainView.xaml.cs

```
namespace Appssss.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Mainview : Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage
    {
        public Mainview(int index)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
            SetPage(index);
        }
        void SetPage(int index)
        {
            CurrentPage = Children[index];
        }
    }
}
```

CustomTabbedPageRenderer.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Appssss.Droid.Renderers;
using Google.Android.Material.Tabs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat;
using static Google.Android.Material.Tabs.TabLayout;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace Appssss.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer, IOnTabSelectedListener
    {
        public CustomTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }
        void IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
        {
            if (tab == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            switch (tab.Text)
            {
                case "Page 1":
                    tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.homeiconselect);
                    break;
                case "Page 2":
                    tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.feedsselect);
                    break;
                case "Page 3":
                    tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.moneysselect);
                    break;
                case "Page 4":
                    tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.chatsselect);
                    break;
                case "Page 5":
                    tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.usericonselect);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
        }
        void IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
        {
            if (tab == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            switch (tab.Text)
            {
                case "Page 1":
                    tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.homeicon);
                    break;
                case "Page 2":
                    tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.feeds);
                    break;
                case "Page 3":
                    tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.moneys);
                    break;
                case "Page 4":
                    tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.chats);
                    break;
                case "Page 5":
                    tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.usericon);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the result, I noticed it still doesn't change as expected:

[image]

[image]

I have created different icons, and as noticed it is still not working. I haven't tried it on iOS yet.

**Update 2**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Appssss.Droid.Renderers;
using Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation;
using Google.Android.Material.Tabs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat;
using static Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation.BottomNavigationView;
using static Google.Android.Material.Tabs.TabLayout;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace Appssss.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer, IOnTabSelectedListener
    {
        public CustomTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                IEnumerable<View> children = GetAllChildViews(ViewGroup);
                BottomNavigationView bottomNavBar = (BottomNavigationView)children.SingleOrDefault(view => view is BottomNavigationView);

                if (bottomNavBar != null)
                {
                    bottomNavBar.NavigationItemSelected += BottomNavBar_NavigationItemSelected;
                    bottomNavBar.Menu.GetItem(0).SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.diamond);
                }

            }
        }
        int previous;
        private void BottomNavBar_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            var current = e.Item.ItemId;

            switch (e.Item.ToString())
            {
                case "Page 1":
                    e.Item.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.diamond);
                    break;
                case "Page 2":
                    e.Item.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.diamond);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }


            var previousView = sender as BottomNavigationView;
            IMenu menu = previousView.Menu;
            var previousItem = menu.GetItem(previous);


            if (previousItem.IsChecked)
            {
                switch (previousItem.ToString())
                {
                    case "Page 1":
                        previousItem.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.cactus_24px);
                        break;
                    case "Page 2":
                        previousItem.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.cactus_24px);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }


            }

            previous = current;
        }

        private IEnumerable<View> GetAllChildViews(View view)
        {
            if (!(view is ViewGroup group))
                return new List<View> { view };

            List<View> result = new List<View>();
            int childCount = group.ChildCount;

            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
            {
                View child = group.GetChildAt(i);
                List<View> childList = new List<View> { child };
                childList.AddRange(GetAllChildViews(child));
                result.AddRange(childList);
            }

            return result.Distinct();
        }
    }
}
```

Get error:

[image]
[image]

I tried

[image]

**Update3**

[image]

[image]

It doesn't seem to use the library: `using static Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation.BottomNavigationView;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A easy way is to change icon when you selected the tab. Use two icons, a black one, a red one.

Normally, if we want to change the icon color, one way is to set the background like the result(the second screenshot) you post. The second way is to use the Material Icons instead of image source.

But all the ways would not change the color to red and left two black lines as the example you want.

A Complex method is to draw a new image when the Tab selected. Xamarin.Forms provided several ways to do that:

- Skiasharp: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/
- Shapes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/path

**Updated:**

You could do this in custom renderer.

**Android:** Android provide a class `IOnTabSelectedListener` to listener the selected and unseledted status of the tab. A simple code below for your reference.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace App18.Droid
{
public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer: TabbedPageRenderer, IOnTabSelectedListener
{
    public CustomTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    void IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
    {
        if (tab == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (tab.Text)
        {
            case "Page 1":
                tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);
                break;
            case "Page 2":
                tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    void IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
    {
        if (tab == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (tab.Text)
        {
            case "Page 1":
                tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.cactus_24px);
                break;
            case "Page 2":
                tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.cactus_24px);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
  
}
}
```

**iOS:** For the ios, you could use ViewControllerSelected to register the method `ViewControllerSelected`.
For more details, check the link below. [how to make the tabbed page navigate when clicked on the same tab text/icon twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58763559/how-to-make-the-tabbed-page-navigate-when-clicked-on-the-same-tab-text-icon-twic)

**Updated2:**

**Android:** For the tabs on the bottom, you need to get access to the native `BottomNavigationView`.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace App18.Droid
{
public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer, IOnTabSelectedListener
{
    public CustomTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<View> children = GetAllChildViews(ViewGroup);
            BottomNavigationView bottomNavBar = (BottomNavigationView)children.SingleOrDefault(view => view is BottomNavigationView);

            if (bottomNavBar != null)
            {               
                bottomNavBar.NavigationItemSelected += BottomNavBar_NavigationItemSelected;
                bottomNavBar.Menu.GetItem(0).SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.diamond);
            }

        }
    }
    int previous; 
    private void BottomNavBar_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
         var current = e.Item.ItemId;

        switch (e.Item.ToString())
        {
            case "Page 1":
                e.Item.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.diamond);
                break;
            case "Page 2":
                e.Item.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.diamond);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }       
        

        var previousView = sender as BottomNavigationView;
        IMenu menu = previousView.Menu;
        var previousItem = menu.GetItem(previous);
       

        if (previousItem.IsChecked)
        {
            switch (previousItem.ToString())
            {
                case "Page 1":
                    previousItem.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.cactus_24px);
                    break;
                case "Page 2":
                    previousItem.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.cactus_24px);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
           
            
        }

        previous = current;
    }

    private IEnumerable<View> GetAllChildViews(View view)
    {
        if (!(view is ViewGroup group))
            return new List<View> { view };

        List<View> result = new List<View>();
        int childCount = group.ChildCount;

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            View child = group.GetChildAt(i);
            List<View> childList = new List<View> { child };
            childList.AddRange(GetAllChildViews(child));
            result.AddRange(childList);
        }

        return result.Distinct();
    }
}
}
```

**Update3:**

For the errors of View, use `Android.Views.View` instead of `Xamarin.Forms.View`.

```
using View = Android.Views.View;
```

For the errors of the Item, i added all the code with references which you used, no error with the item. Clean the bin and obj folder to rebuild the project again.

**Update4**:

Declare a `TabbedPage` instance variables outside any function. And set the value when `bottomNavBar` not null.

```
 TabbedPage tabbedPage;
    protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<View> children = GetAllChildViews(ViewGroup);
            BottomNavigationView bottomNavBar = (BottomNavigationView)children.SingleOrDefault(view => view is BottomNavigationView);
            if (bottomNavBar != null)
            {
                tabbedPage = e.NewElement;
                bottomNavBar.NavigationItemSelected += BottomNavBar_NavigationItemSelected;
                bottomNavBar.Menu.GetItem(0).SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.diamond_24);
            }
        }
    }
```

Set the `CurrentPage` of `tabbedPage` in `BottomNavBar_NavigationItemSelected`.

```
   private void BottomNavBar_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var current = e.Item.ItemId;
        switch (e.Item.ToString())
        {
            case "Page 1":
                e.Item.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.diamond_24);
                break;
            case "Page 2":
                e.Item.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.diamond_24);
                break;
            case "Page 3":
                e.Item.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.diamond_24);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        var previousView = sender as BottomNavigationView;
        IMenu menu = previousView.Menu;
        var previousItem = menu.GetItem(previous);
         if (previous != current)
        {
            if (previousItem.IsChecked)
            {
                switch (previousItem.ToString())
                {
                    case "Page 1":
                        previousItem.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.cactus_24);
                        break;
                    case "Page 2":
                        previousItem.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.cactus_24);
                        break;
                    case "Page 3":
                        previousItem.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.cactus_24);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }

        }
        tabbedPage.CurrentPage = tabbedPage.Children[current];
        previous = current;
    }
```

Comment: So in your opinion the easiest way is to create 2 images before and after. I found it to be pretty good too. Do you have specific instructions for this on ios and android in Xamarin?

Comment: I would update the code ASAP.

Comment: Please check mu update.

Comment: I followed your instructions, however it still doesn't work. You can check in the update section above. Thank you

Comment: @ChimDiTru That code works for the normal tab on Android which tab shows on the top. For the bottom tab, i would feedback ASAP.

Comment: Please check my update.

Comment: As in your update, is it fixed to only work for a single tab with Resource.Drawable.diamond? I like your first idea for each different tab. Can you customize it?

Comment: For the top tabs, Android provide the `IOnTabSelectedListener` to listen the tab selected and unselected. I could get the specific tab which selected or unselected. I could use the Tab.Text to change the icon for the specific tab.

Comment: For the bottom tabs, we need to use the `BottomNavigationView`. I use the previous index and current index to represent the unselected item and selected item. I just provide a example to change the icon when selected and change the icon back when unselected. For the specific tab with specific icon, you need to get the item using index (GetItem(previous)) to judge that the tab title.

Comment: I missed the judgement for the specific tab. I would edit my code later.

Comment: @ChimDiTru Check the code in `BottomNavBar_NavigationItemSelected`.

Comment: I've been sitting all day to study the code you sent, but it gives me many errors that I've updated above. I still don't understand it

Comment: @ChimDiTru Check my update3.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine when I create new project. However when I put in my project: `NavigationItemSelected` and `NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs` it doesn't work. Meanwhile I have used the library: `using static Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation.BottomNavigationView;` and it doesn't seem to be enabled.

Comment: I don't use any TabbedPage Plugin other than the default on Xamarin. I have updated3 above

Comment: If you use the latest version 5.0.0.2291 of Xamarin.Forms, it would install the AndroidX packages. And `NavigationItemSelected` of `BottomNavigationView` would throw the error because of the old packages. For now, i use the Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012. It works.

Comment: We use custom renderer to call navite specification of each platforms on Xamarin.Forms. `Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation.BottomNavigationView` is special for the Native Android not a third-party plugin. You could check the Android Developer: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView

Comment: This package is not supported by AndroidX. If you install the AndroidX, we could not use the `NavigationItemSelected` event of `BottomNavigationView`.

Comment: Actually I am using Xamarin version 5.0.0.2291. So is there any way to fix this problem. I can't downgrade the version of Xamarin.

Comment: A easy way is to downgrade. Right click the project solution. Choose the Manage NuGet Packages for the Solution. And then choose Xamarin.Forms on the left side and tick the Forms, android, ios on the right side of NuGet to install the Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012 would fix this issue.

Comment: I have downgraded Xamarin version 5.0.0.0.2012. The icons have really changed. However, when I click the Tabs, the content doesn't change =]]]]. For example, when I click on Tab Page2, it doesn't switch to Page2,.... it only gets the first Page1, similar to the rest of Tabs =]]]]

Comment: Glad that you could change icon when you select the tab. For the code of the tabbedpage, it seems you use the four contentpages: Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4. Have you do any navigation in your code? If no, have you change the default layout of each page?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I make each Tab a different page. You can see in my content above. <views:Page1 Title="Page 1" IconImageSource="homeicon" BackgroundColor="#fff"/>
     <views:Page2 Title="Page 2" IconImageSource="feeds" BackgroundColor="#fff"/>.... If I don't use: CustomTabbedPageRenderer when I click between Tabs it switches pages fine.

Comment: ohhhhh, my fault. I forget to add the code to set the current page of tabbedpage when use the bottom view. See my update4.

Comment: Thank you, it works well, but there is a limitation that I click twice on 1 Tab, the icon will return to default, but I think it is not too important =]]]]. I have another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518943/how-to-add-dot-icon-for-tabbedpage-strong-xamarin, if you have free time you can check it out, thank you very much.

Comment: Add a if statement to judge `previous != current` before changing the icon for previousItem. I edited the code.

Comment: It's really good, thank you