# How to add dot icon for TabbedPage strong Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to add a red dot as shown below for TabbedPage. I have searched the internet but it doesn't look like anything. It looks like Badges but it's not. I want to permanently assign it at any time. I also don't know what keywords to search for exactly. For Xamarin iOS and Android.

[image]

**MainView.xaml**

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Appssss.Views"
            x:Class="Appssss.Views.Mainview">
  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
    <views:AboutPage Title="Page 1" IconImageSource="homeicon" BackgroundColor="#fff"/>
    <views:LoginPage Title="Page 2" IconImageSource="feeds" BackgroundColor="#fff"/>
    <views:AboutPage Title="Page 3" IconImageSource="moneys" BackgroundColor="#fbfbfb" />
    <views:AboutPage Title="Page 4" IconImageSource="chats" BackgroundColor="#fff" />
    <views:AboutPage Title="Page 5" IconImageSource="usericon" BackgroundColor="#fff"/>
</TabbedPage>
```

Ask for help from everyone. Thank you

**Update**

**MyTabDotRenderer.cs**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(MyTabDotRenderer))]
namespace XXXX.iOS
{
    internal class MyTabDotRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        private bool _initialized;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            //TabBar.ClipsToBounds = true;
            TabBar.TintColor = UIColor.Gray;
            TabBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.White;
            TabBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, int>(this, "Add", (obj, index) => {
                TabBar.addItemBadge(index);
            });
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, int>(this, "Remove", (obj, index) => {
                TabBar.removeItemBadge(index);
            });
        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            if (!_initialized)
            {
                if (TabBar?.Items == null)
                    return;

                foreach (var item in TabBar.Items)
                {
                    item.Image = ScalingImageToSize(item.Image, new CGSize(20, 20)); // set the size here as you want 
                }

                var tabs = Element as TabbedPage;

                if (tabs != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < TabBar.Items.Length; i++)
                    {
                        UpdateItem(TabBar.Items[i], tabs.Children[i].Icon, tabs.Children[i].StyleId);
                    }
                }

                _initialized = true;
            }

            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        }
        private void UpdateItem(UITabBarItem item, string icon, string badgeValue)
        {
            if (item == null) return;

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
            {
                //change icon select
                if (icon.EndsWith(".png"))
                    icon = icon.Replace(".png", "_selected.png");
                else
                    icon += "_selected";

                item.SelectedImage = UIImage.FromBundle(icon);
                item.SelectedImage.AccessibilityIdentifier = icon;
                item.SelectedImage = ScalingImageToSize(item.SelectedImage, new CGSize(20, 20)); // set the size here as you want 
                //change icon select


                UITabBarAppearance app = new UITabBarAppearance();
                app.ConfigureWithOpaqueBackground();
                app.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

                app.StackedLayoutAppearance.Normal.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes() { Font = UIFont.FromName("Roboto Medium", 12), ForegroundColor = Color.FromHex("#808080").ToUIColor() };
                app.StackedLayoutAppearance.Selected.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes() { Font = UIFont.FromName("Roboto Medium", 13), ForegroundColor = Color.FromHex("#00AA13").ToUIColor() };
                item.StandardAppearance = app;

                if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(15, 0))
                {
                    item.ScrollEdgeAppearance = item.StandardAppearance;
                }
            }

        }
        public UIImage ScalingImageToSize(UIImage sourceImage, CGSize newSize)
        {

            if (UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 2.0) //@2x iPhone 6 7 8 
            {
                UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 2.0f);
            }


            else if (UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 3.0) //@3x iPhone 6p 7p 8p...
            {
                UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 3.0f);
            }

            else
            {
                UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(newSize);
            }

            sourceImage.Draw(new CGRect(0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height));

            UIImage newImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

            UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

            return newImage;

        }
    }

    public static class TabbarExtensions
    {

        readonly static int tabBarItemTag = 9999;
        public static void addItemBadge(this UITabBar tabbar, int index)
        {
            if (tabbar.Items != null && tabbar.Items.Length == 0) return;

            if (index >= tabbar.Items.Length) return;

            removeItemBadge(tabbar, index);

            var badgeView = new UIView();
            badgeView.Tag = tabBarItemTag + index;
            badgeView.Layer.CornerRadius = 5;
            badgeView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

            var tabFrame = tabbar.Frame;
            var percentX = (index + 0.56) / tabbar.Items.Length;
            var x = percentX * tabFrame.Width;
            var y = tabFrame.Height * 0.1;
            badgeView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(x, y, 10, 10);
            tabbar.AddSubview(badgeView);
        }

        public static bool removeItemBadge(this UITabBar tabbar, int index)
        {
            foreach (var subView in tabbar.Subviews)
            {
                if (subView.Tag == tabBarItemTag + index)
                {
                    subView.RemoveFromSuperview();
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainView.xaml.cs**

```
public MainView(int index)
{       
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    InitializeComponent();
    On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);

     SetPage(index);
     MessagingCenter.Send<object, int>(this, "Add", 1);
}
void SetPage(int index)
{ 
    CurrentPage = Children[index]; 
}
```

**Update 2**

**CustomTabbedPageRenderer.cs** in project Android

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Appssss.Droid.Renderers;
using Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation;
using Google.Android.Material.Tabs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat;
using static Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation.BottomNavigationView;
using static Google.Android.Material.Tabs.TabLayout;
using View = Android.Views.View;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace Appssss.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
    {
        TabbedPage tabbedPage;
        List<Android.Views.View> list = new List<Android.Views.View>();
        public CustomTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Android.Views.View view = LayoutInflater.From(Context).Inflate(Resource.Drawable.MyView, null);
                list.Add(view);
            }
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null || e.OldElement != null)
                return;

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, int>(this, "Add", (obj, index) => {
                    TabLayout tablayout = (TabLayout)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(1);
                    ViewGroup vgroup = (ViewGroup)tablayout.GetChildAt(0);
                    for (int i = 0; i < vgroup.ChildCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (index == i)
                        {
                            var view = list[i];
                            if (view.Parent != null) break;
                            ViewGroup vvgroup = (ViewGroup)vgroup.GetChildAt(i);
                            MarginLayoutParams layout1 = new MarginLayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams.MatchParent, MarginLayoutParams.MatchParent);
                            layout1.SetMargins(120, -135, 0, 0);
                            vvgroup.AddView(view, layout1);

                            var ll = vvgroup.LayoutParameters as LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
                            ll.SetMargins(0, 30, 0, 0);
                            vvgroup.LayoutParameters = ll;
                        }
                    }
                });
                MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, int>(this, "Remove", (obj, index) => {
                    TabLayout tablayout = (TabLayout)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(1);
                    ViewGroup vgroup = (ViewGroup)tablayout.GetChildAt(0);
                    for (int i = 0; i < vgroup.ChildCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (index == i)
                        {
                            var view = list[i];
                            if (view.Parent == null) break;
                            ViewGroup vvgroup = (ViewGroup)vgroup.GetChildAt(i);
                            vvgroup.RemoveView(view);

                            var ll = vvgroup.LayoutParameters as LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
                            ll.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                            vvgroup.LayoutParameters = ll;
                        }
                    }
                });



                IEnumerable<View> children = GetAllChildViews(ViewGroup);
                BottomNavigationView bottomNavBar = (BottomNavigationView)children.SingleOrDefault(view => view is BottomNavigationView);
                if (bottomNavBar != null)
                {
                    tabbedPage = e.NewElement;
                    bottomNavBar.NavigationItemSelected += BottomNavBar_NavigationItemSelected;
                    bottomNavBar.Menu.GetItem(0).SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.homeiconselect);
                }
            }
        }
        int previous;
        private void BottomNavBar_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            var current = e.Item.ItemId;
            switch (e.Item.ToString())
            {
                case "Page 1":
                    e.Item.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.homeiconselect);
                    break;
                case "Page 2":
                    e.Item.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.feedsselect);
                    break;
                case "Page 3":
                    e.Item.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.moneysselect);
                    break;
                case "Page 4":
                    e.Item.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.chatsselect);
                    break;
                case "Page 5":
                    e.Item.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.usericonselect);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            var previousView = sender as BottomNavigationView;
            IMenu menu = previousView.Menu;
            var previousItem = menu.GetItem(previous);

            if (previous != current)
            {
                if (previousItem.IsChecked)
                {
                    switch (previousItem.ToString())
                    {
                        case "Page 1":
                            previousItem.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.homeicon);
                            break;
                        case "Page 2":
                            previousItem.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.feeds);
                            break;
                        case "Page 3":
                            previousItem.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.moneys);
                            break;
                        case "Page 4":
                            previousItem.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.chats);
                            break;
                        case "Page 5":
                            previousItem.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.usericon);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            tabbedPage.CurrentPage = tabbedPage.Children[current];
            previous = current;
        }

        private IEnumerable<View> GetAllChildViews(View view)
        {
            if (!(view is ViewGroup group))
                return new List<View> { view };

            List<View> result = new List<View>();
            int childCount = group.ChildCount;

            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
            {
                View child = group.GetChildAt(i);
                List<View> childList = new List<View> { child };
                childList.AddRange(GetAllChildViews(child));
                result.AddRange(childList);
            }

            return result.Distinct();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainView.xaml.cs**

```
public Mainview(int index)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
    SetPage(index);
    
}
void SetPage(int index)
{
    CurrentPage = Children[index];
}
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    MessagingCenter.Send<object, int>(this, "Add", 1);
    ///On iOS this works fine 
}
```

1. Add a xml in drawable folder called MyView.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <Button android:background="@drawable/Reddot"  
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

2. Add a xml in drawable folder called Reddot.xml

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
    <size android:width="12dp" android:height="12dp"/>
    </shape>
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be achieved by creating a `custom renderer` for TabbedPage .

#### iOS Solution

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(MyTabRenderer))]
namespace MyForms.iOS
{
    internal class MyTabRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, int>(this, "Add", (obj,index) => {
                TabBar.addItemBadge(index);
            });
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, int>(this, "Remove", (obj,index) => {
                TabBar.removeItemBadge(index);
            });
        }
    }

    public static class TabbarExtensions
    {

        readonly static int tabBarItemTag = 9999;
        public static void addItemBadge(this UITabBar tabbar, int index)
        {
            if (tabbar.Items != null && tabbar.Items.Length == 0) return;

            if (index >= tabbar.Items.Length) return;

            removeItemBadge(tabbar, index);

            var badgeView = new UIView();
            badgeView.Tag = tabBarItemTag + index;
            badgeView.Layer.CornerRadius = 5;
            badgeView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

            var tabFrame = tabbar.Frame;
            var percentX = (index + 0.56) / tabbar.Items.Length;
            var x = percentX * tabFrame.Width;
            var y = tabFrame.Height * 0.1;
            badgeView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(x, y, 10, 10);
            tabbar.AddSubview(badgeView);
        }

        public static bool removeItemBadge(this UITabBar tabbar, int index)
        {
            foreach(var subView in tabbar.Subviews)
            {
                if(subView.Tag == tabBarItemTag + index)
                {
                    subView.RemoveFromSuperview();
                    return true; 
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

#### Android Solution

1. Add a xml in `drawable` folder called `Reddot.xml` .

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>

    <size android:width="12dp" android:height="12dp"/>
</shape>
```

2. Add a xml in `drawable` folder called `MyView.xml` .

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <Button android:background="@drawable/Reddot"  
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

3.custom renderer

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace MyForms.Droid
{
    public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer 
    {
        List<Android.Views.View> list = new List<Android.Views.View>();
        public CustomTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3;i++)
            {
                Android.Views.View view = LayoutInflater.From(Context).Inflate(Resource.Drawable.MyView, null);
                list.Add(view);
            }
        }
       
        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null || e.OldElement != null)
                return;

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, int>(this, "Add", (obj, index) => {
                TabLayout tablayout = (TabLayout)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(1);
                ViewGroup vgroup = (ViewGroup)tablayout.GetChildAt(0);
                for (int i = 0; i < vgroup.ChildCount; i++)
                {
                    if(index == i)
                    {
                        var view = list[i];
                        if (view.Parent != null) break;
                        ViewGroup vvgroup = (ViewGroup)vgroup.GetChildAt(i);
                        MarginLayoutParams layout1 = new MarginLayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams.MatchParent, MarginLayoutParams.MatchParent);               
                        layout1.SetMargins(120, -135, 0, 0);
                        vvgroup.AddView(view,layout1);

                        var ll = vvgroup.LayoutParameters as LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
                        ll.SetMargins(0, 30, 0,0 );
                        vvgroup.LayoutParameters = ll;
                    }
                }
            });

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, int>(this, "Remove", (obj, index) => {
                TabLayout tablayout = (TabLayout)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(1);
                ViewGroup vgroup = (ViewGroup)tablayout.GetChildAt(0);
                for (int i = 0; i < vgroup.ChildCount; i++)
                {
                    if(index == i)
                    {
                        var view = list[i];
                        if (view.Parent == null) break;
                        ViewGroup vvgroup = (ViewGroup)vgroup.GetChildAt(i);
                        vvgroup.RemoveView(view);

                        var ll = vvgroup.LayoutParameters as LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
                        ll.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        vvgroup.LayoutParameters = ll;
                    }
                }
            });                    
        }
    }
}
```

#### Usage in Forms project

```
//add red dot
MessagingCenter.Send<object, int>(this, "Add", 1);
//remove red dot
MessagingCenter.Send<object, int>(this, "Remove", 1);
```

#### Screen shot

[image]
[image]

Comment: I added everything. As in my update above. My project has set icon size, color,.... of TabbedPage. I tried it but it still doesn't show dot red, is there some kind of conflict here? Thank you for watching it. I'm checking on Xamarin iOS

Comment: Is `MainView` TabbedPage ?  Try to place `MessagingCenter.Send<object, int>(this, "Add", 1);` in single page like `AboutPage.cs` or click button to trigger it .

Comment: My confusion. However I tried to create a new Project, do more updates above, it still doesn't work. I am testing on iphone 11promax iOS 15.0

Comment: Ok then would you like to provide your project to us for test ? You can upload to github and attach the link here .

Comment: I uploaded it to Github: https://github.com/chimditruvn/Appssss You can see it

Comment: I  checked your project , the page constructor calls before custom renderer `OnElementChanged` , so it never gets triggered , moving ` MessagingCenter.Send<object, int>(this, "Add", 1);`  to `OnAppearing` method solves the problem .

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it only shows dot red when I leave that Tab. I want to dot red it always shows. Do you have any solution to fix it? Help me out with the answer, I'm pretty vague about it. Thank you

Comment: Move the code to `OnAppearing` method in `Mainview` .

Comment: Thank you, if you have a guide for Android too, that's great.

Comment: Check my update

Comment: I tried, however it doesn't work. Maybe TabbedPage is at the bottom. I have updated 2 above. Thank you for watching it.